# hide an image from facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I want Facebook to ignore a particular image on a page. Is there any tag I can use that will hide an image from Facebook when users share a page?

We are using Joomla 3.4. The article pages that have an intro section that displays on category listing pages but is hidden on the actual article page. The intro section has a thumbnail 75 x 75.

In the main body of the article there is a larger image that we would like to display on Facebook but the og:image always selects the thumbnail first.

Is there any way I can add some parameter to the thumbnail so that it will be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you explicitly specify the larger image in your `og:image` tag? If you specify more than one `og:image`, as far as I know the first one is selected.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#images
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/optimizing#cachingimages
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images